# Remote Server Management Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-control

In Windows Server 2008 I can enable remote management by using `winrm quickconfig` and then I can remotely manage the server from my Windows 7 desktop.

But, in Windows Server 2003 this command doesn't work. How do I enable remote management in Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 0):

On Server 2003 you'll need to install the Windows Remote Management core and Powershell before you can enable WinRM. You can download these here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10512

Then you can run the command `winrm quickconfig` to start the service in default mode.

You can also enable just for PowerShell remote management. This document sheds more light on that process: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/03/how-to-install-powershell-on-windows-server-2003-and-enable-remote-powershell-managementall-servers-should-have-this-done/